# How to solve Permissions policy in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sms

I was having an Android application written in ionic and cord-ova. Google play has removed the app for permission policy.

Issue: Violation of the Permissions policy

We only allow apps to access Call Log or SMS data for permitted uses and only to enable the app’s core functionality.

I searched my project and I found it was using ngCordova.plugins.sms.

Is removing the plugin, will solve the problem.

Thanks.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-remove-the-specified-permissions-for-sms-from-apps-manifest-for-an-ionic-3-android-app/150567

Answer (score 0):

Yes, removing the plugin should get your app approved however if your app uses SMS (for whatever reason) then you will need to find another solution. Also if your app uses another plugin that violates Google Play's policies then it could also be rejected.

Comment: Hi, we are facing similar SMS permission issues while upload the app in google play store. can you please help us. we have to read SMS in our application.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/permissions-policy

Permissions-Policy: autoplay=;

works